# Positive eigenvectors for nonnegative matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $ A $ a nonnegative matrix (i.e. all the entries of $ A $ are real, nonnegative) of dimensions $ n \times n $. Is it true that the conditions:

- $ A x_1 = \lambda_1 x_1 $
- $ A x_2 = \lambda_2 x_2 $
- $ x_1 \gg 0, x_2 \gg 0 $ (i.e. all the components of $ x_1 $ and $ x_2 $ are strictly positive)

imply $ \lambda_1 = \lambda_2 $? (obviously $ \lambda_1, \lambda_2 $ are real scalars, while $ x_1, x_2 $ are real vectors).

Comment: [Wikipedia on the Perron-Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Positive_matrices). Point 2 seems to give a partially affirmative answer

Comment: Yes, I already know this result. If $ A $ is irreducible, the problem is solved by the theorem you mentioned. But I do not make on $ A $ any assumption of this type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. This is because when $A\ge0$, its spectral radius $\rho(A)$ is the only eigenvalue that can possibly possess a *positive* eigenvector. (That doesn't mean $\rho(A)$ always has a positive eigenvector — consider e.g. $A=$ the $2\times2$ nontrivial nilpotent Jordan block. Nor does it mean that $\rho(A)$ is the only eigenvalue that has a *nonnegative* eigenvector — consider e.g. $A=\operatorname{diag}(1,0)$.)

Suppose the contrary that $Av=\lambda v$ for some $v>0$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb C\setminus\{\rho(A)\}$. Then $\lambda$ must be a positive real number (it cannot be zero, otherwise $Av=0$ and in turn $A=0$, which is a contradiction to the assumption that $\lambda\ne\rho(A)$). Hence $0<\lambda<\rho(A)$. Let $B=\frac1{\rho(A)}A$ and $b=\frac{\lambda}{\rho(A)}$. Then $Bv=bv$ and $0\le b<1$. It follows that
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}v^TB^mv=\lim_{m\to\infty}b^m\|v\|^2=0.\tag{1}
$$
Since $v^TB^mv$ is a *positively* weighted sum of all entries of a nonnegative matrix, $(1)$ implies that $\lim_{m\to\infty}B^m=0$. Consequently,
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\rho(B)^m=\lim_{m\to\infty}\rho(B^m)=\rho\left(\lim_{m\to\infty}B^m\right)=0.
$$
But this is a contradiction because $\rho(B)=\rho\left(\frac1{\rho(A)}A\right)=1$.

**Edit.** Here is a simpler proof if one knows Perron-Frobenius theorem. Let $Av=\lambda v$ for some $\lambda>0$ and $v>0$. By Perron-Frobenius theorem $A$ has a nonnegative left eigenvector $u$ for the eigenvalue $\rho(A)$. Then $\rho(A)u^Tv=(u^TA)v=u^T(Av)=\lambda u^Tv$. Since $u\ne0,\,u\ge0$ and $v>0$, the product $u^Tv$ is positive. Therefore $\rho(A)=\lambda$, i.e., the only possible eigenvalue that has a positive eigenvector is $\rho(A)$.